# Deeplink in android not working

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I am trying to build an app where if the user will click on the web link it will redirect to the playstore with a particular id.Then after installing the app I will get the id and do the rest of the process.Currently it is redirecting to the playstore but I am unable to get the id.

Here is my manifest file

```
 <receiver    android:name=".deeplinking.ReferrerReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true" >
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
```

My broadcast

```
public class ReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ReferrerReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            Log.e("ReferrerReceiver", "Intent is null");
            return;
        }else{
         String key= (String) extras.get("referrer);
    }
}
```

My weburl link

```
intent://url/soham#Intent;scheme=http;package=package;S.name=P208;S.browser_fallback_url= http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package&referrer=P208;end"
```

Comment: Do you open the application install page in Web Browser or Play Store application? Looks like in browser. I think you have to open it in Play Store application.

Comment: I am opening in the playstore